# PFBC Disable select list option

Tags: php, html, forms, pfbc

I am using PHP Form Builder Class to implement a form. I want the intial value in the select box to be "Referrer" but to be a disabled option, so that one of the other three options has to be selected.

Here is an example of the code I have currently:

```
 $dform->addElement(new Element\Select("Referrer:", "referrer", array("0" => "Referrer", "1" => "New Customer", "2" => "Returning Customer", "3" => "Referred by Friend")));
```

How can I add the disabled attribute to the first option "Referrer" in the select list?

Thanks